# Why I cant get unity touch input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't get touch input from unity. I don't know why.

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("aaaa");
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Debug.Log(touch.phase);
        Debug.Log(touch.position);
    }
```

Comment: how are you testing it? on PC or on a smartphone? Touch is not the same as mouse

Comment: smartphone. It fixed itself tho. I didnt do anything but right now it is working as it should be

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the documentation, you absolutely should: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

Are you **actually** making touches?

Also, simplify three *Debug.Log*'s into one:

```
Debug.Log($"aaaa {touch.phase} {touch.position}")
```

Comment: I do believe i am making touches. Thanks for log addition !